# Struggling to center content

Tags: html, css

I'd like my calculator to be centered in the middle of my page, I managed to get this to work until I added a footer.

The best I can do is have my calculator stuck top left of my page!

Can anyone help:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, lightgray, white);
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 275px;
  /*  height: 415px; */
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.sub-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  /* height: 100%;  */
  /*   width: 800%; */
}

.display {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  /* border: 1px solid white; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  /*   margin: 0 0 5% 0;  */
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

#result-display {
  margin-right: 8%;
}

.button-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  width: 68px;
  height: 65px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: rgba(209, 190, 200, 0.17);
}

.item:hover,
[data-type="nonNumber"]:hover {
  background-color: rgba(252, 252, 252, 0.2);
}

#Enter {
  width: 206px;
}

#Enter {
  background-color: orange;
}

#Enter:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 165, 0, 0.6);
}

#AC {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

[data-type="nonNumber"] {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

footer {
  background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.3);
  padding: 8px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="sub-container">
          <div class="display">
            <p id="result-display">

            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="button-grid">
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="7" data-type="number">
                7
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="8" data-type="number">
                8
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="9" data-type="number">
                9
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="divide" data-type="nonNumberFunction">
                &divide;
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="4" data-type="number">
                4
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="5" data-type="number">
                5
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="6" data-type="number">
                6
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="multiply" data-type="nonNumberFunction">
                &times;
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="1" data-type="number">
                1
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="2" data-type="number">
                2
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="3" data-type="number">
                3
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="subtract" data-type="nonNumberFunction">
                &minus;
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="0" data-type="number">
                0
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="decimal" data-type="nonNumber">
                .
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="AC" data-type="nonNumber">
                AC
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="add" data-type="nonNumberFunction">
                &plus;
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="Enter" data-type="nonNumber">
                &equals;
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="Backspace" data-type="nonNumber">
                DEL
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
      <footer><span>Made with &lt;3 by <a href="https://www.twitter.com/mrsamlj" target="_blank">@MrSamLJ</a></span></footer>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s9ebLdvt/13/

Comment: `margin:auto` applied to the `.container` class should move the calculator to the centre

Comment: YES! Thank-you!!! The old margin:auto...!

Answer (score 0):

In simple way, use `margin: auto` for the `.container`.

Or you just need to make the `<body>` its normal `display` and make `wrapper` as `inline-flex`:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, lightgray, white);
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 275px;
  /*  height: 415px; */
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.sub-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  /* height: 100%;  */
  /*   width: 800%; */
}

.display {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  /* border: 1px solid white; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
  /*   margin: 0 0 5% 0;  */
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

#result-display {
  margin-right: 8%;
}

.button-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  width: 68px;
  height: 65px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: rgba(209, 190, 200, 0.17);
}

.item:hover,
[data-type="nonNumber"]:hover {
  background-color: rgba(252, 252, 252, 0.2);
}

#Enter {
  width: 206px;
}

#Enter {
  background-color: orange;
}

#Enter:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 165, 0, 0.6);
}

#AC {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

[data-type="nonNumber"] {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

footer {
  background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.3);
  padding: 8px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="sub-container">
          <div class="display">
            <p id="result-display">

            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="button-grid">
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="7" data-type="number">
                7
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="8" data-type="number">
                8
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="9" data-type="number">
                9
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="divide" data-type="nonNumberFunction">
                &divide;
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="4" data-type="number">
                4
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="5" data-type="number">
                5
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="6" data-type="number">
                6
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="multiply" data-type="nonNumberFunction">
                &times;
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="1" data-type="number">
                1
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="2" data-type="number">
                2
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="3" data-type="number">
                3
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="subtract" data-type="nonNumberFunction">
                &minus;
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="0" data-type="number">
                0
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="decimal" data-type="nonNumber">
                .
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="AC" data-type="nonNumber">
                AC
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="add" data-type="nonNumberFunction">
                &plus;
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="Enter" data-type="nonNumber">
                &equals;
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="item" id="Backspace" data-type="nonNumber">
                DEL
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
      <footer><span>Made with &lt;3 by <a href="https://www.twitter.com/mrsamlj" target="_blank">@MrSamLJ</a></span></footer>
    </div>
```

Preview

[image: preview]